# Android button text color does not change

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a quiz app that has a question and to answer options. When the wrong answer (button) is clicked, the text color for that specific button turns red, as it should. However, when the right button is clicked, the text color for that particular button should turn green, wait a second, and then move on to the next question.

I have spent days trying to figure out why it doesn't work, googled for answers, but I still can't make it work.

I have tried using Handlers and Runnables, but it still doesn't work.

I have posted the full code for the activity below.

Please help!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.question_layout);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    subject = (Subject) i.getSerializableExtra(Globals.SUBJECT);
    questions = subject.getQuestions();
    subjectId = subject.getSubjectId();
    appPreferences = new AppPreferences();

    livesLeft = 3;
    index = 0;
    maxQuestions = questions.size();
    maxIndex = maxQuestions - 1;

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setMax(maxQuestions);

    answer1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAnswer1);
    answer2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAnswer2);

    setQuestionsAndAnswers(index);

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSubjectName);
    textView.setText(subject.getSubjectName());
}

private void setQuestionsAndAnswers(int index)
{
    currentQuestion = questions.get(index);

    // Set question
    TextView textViewQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewQuestion);
    textViewQuestion.setText(currentQuestion.getQuestion());

    // Set correct answer
    correctAnswer = currentQuestion.getCorrectAnswer();
    sourceUrl = currentQuestion.getSourceUrl();
    sourceText = currentQuestion.getSourceText();

    // Set answer #1
    initializeButton(answer1, currentQuestion.getAnswer1());

    // Set answer #2
    initializeButton(answer2, currentQuestion.getAnswer2());
    // Set source
    TextView textViewSource = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSource);
    textViewSource.setText(sourceText);
    textViewSource.setPaintFlags(Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);

    textViewSource.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(sourceUrl));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    });

    // Update progress
    updateProgress(index);
}

private void initializeButton(Button button, String answer)
{
    button.setText(answer);
    button.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    button.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    button.setEnabled(true);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            onClickContent(view);               
        }
    });
}

private void onClickContent(View view)
{
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    final Button button = (Button) view;
    String answer = button.getText().toString();

    if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase(correctAnswer))
    {
        button.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (index == maxIndex)
        {
            appPreferences.editPreferences(context, Globals.PREFERENCE_KEY + subjectId, true);

            playSound(Globals.SOUND_QUIZ_COMPLETED);

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Quiz \"" + subject.getSubjectName() + "\" finished",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            finish();
        } else
        {
            playSound(Globals.SOUND_CORRECT_ANSER);

            // Go to next question
            index++;
            setQuestionsAndAnswers(index);
        }

    } else
    {
        if (livesLeft == 1)
        {
            playSound(Globals.SOUND_GAME_OVER);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Game over", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            finish();
        } else
        {
            playSound(Globals.SOUND_WRONG_ANSWER);

            button.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            button.setEnabled(false);
            livesLeft--;
            TextView lives = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLives);
            lives.setText("Lives: " + livesLeft);
        }
    }
}

private void updateProgress(int progress)
{
    progressBar.setProgress(progress++);
}

private void playSound(int songId)
{
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), songId);
    mp.start();
}
```

Comment: go back to using handlers and also use this rather `if(answer.toLowerCase().equals(correctAnswer.toLowerCase())){` and see if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `Thread.sleep(1000);` in your case runs on MAIN thread, causes MAIN thread to sleep, it's not suggested.

You may `view.postDelayed` to load next question after a delay,

```
private void onClickContent(View view)
{
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    final Button button = (Button) view;
    String answer = button.getText().toString();

    if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase(correctAnswer))
    {
        button.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

        if (index == maxIndex)
        {
            appPreferences.editPreferences(context, Globals.PREFERENCE_KEY + subjectId, true);

            playSound(Globals.SOUND_QUIZ_COMPLETED);

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Quiz \"" + subject.getSubjectName() + "\" finished",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            finish();
        } else
        {
            playSound(Globals.SOUND_CORRECT_ANSER);

            // Go to next question
            index++;
            // Go to next question after 1000ms
            view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    setQuestionsAndAnswers(index);
                }
            }, 1000); //here delays 1000ms
        }

    } 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use for the same purpose. It should work...

```
button.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Reset Color if you want to...
        // Start new question here
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but then the next question loads before the text color turns green.

Comment: The run() should contain the code to move to the next question.

Comment: @ACetin and what if you try to delay the loading of the next question?

Comment: @ACetin I corrected my answer. Everything inside the Runnable will start after 1000 milliseconds, or whatever amount of time you want to.

Comment: karaokyo you were right, the loading of the next question should be in run() as @yummi suggested